# median of 3, quicksort with iterators

Tags: c++, algorithm, pivot, quicksort

I'm trying choose the pivot for quicksort by taking the median of the first, last and center element of the vector to be sorted. I've seen a lot of implementations with the range in terms of int, but i was trying to do it with iterators.(it shouldn't be that different anyway). However, my code dosent quite do what i want it to. It works when T is an int but for some other classes it times out. Any ideas? 
Here is the code:

```
template <class T>
int ParallelSort::partition(typename vector<T>::iterator &start, typename        vector<T>::iterator &end)
{
int Index = (end-start)/2;
T tmpSwap = start[Index];
//the three if statement get the three part median for the vector. 
if(start[Index] < *start)
{
    start[Index] = *start;
    *start = tmpSwap;
}
if(*end < *start)
{
    tmpSwap = *end;
    *end = *start;
    *start = tmpSwap;
}
if(*end < start[Index])
{
    tmpSwap = start[Index];
    start[Index] = *end;
    *end = tmpSwap;
}
T pivot = start[Index];
//rest of the code .....
//i'm sure that the rest of the code works correctly
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be using `typename std::vector<T>::size_type`, not `int`. Secondly, use `std::distance` to find the difference between two iterators, which should be stored in `typename std::vector<T>::difference_type`. Finally, iterators are generally passed by value, not by reference.

Your problem is likely the fact that you're dereferencing `end`. This is undefined behaviour - you probably wanted to dereference `--end`.

Also, the whole point of Iterators is so that you do not limit yourself to a specific container (in theory, anyway). This should probably be written with the signature:

```
template <typename SizeType, typename RandomAccessIterator>
SizeType ParallelSort::partition(RandomAccessIterator start, RandomAccessIterator end)
```

Comment: I'm already decrementing `end` before it is passed into this function, so i dont think that is the problem. I tried changing the type of the int to size_type and also tried difference_type, but it dosent work.